# Is it possible to have non stateless dimensions in OR-Tools VRP?

Tags: or-tools

I use the VRP from OR-Tools to create routes for delivery of parcels. In general, the routes are composed by 20 to 30 delivery locations and are served using motorbikes.

What we see in the reality is that, when we have several parcels to deliver in a radius of 40m-50m, the courier can deliver several parcels with only one stop. However, if the parcels have larger distances, the courier needs to start and stop the moto every time. It means that the service time of one delivery depends on the location of the previous.

AFAIK, the distance dimension in OR-Tools is stateless, since only from_node, to_node are passed as arguments, and I don't find the way to include the explained behavior in the model.

Something I tried is to check if the distance from a location A to a location B is lower than 50m, and if it is, the service time is lower. The only drawback of this is that if instead of having all the parcels in a circle of radius 50m, we have parcels separated by 40m in a straight line, the model would assume that the service time is always low.

Does anyone know a way to include this kind of dependent costs?

Comment: why don't you merge the visit within this 50m radius ?

Comment: Merging sounds like a solution.. the only point is which delivery locations should I use as a center of the circle? Should I apply a greedy approach and start merging those with higher number of potential neighbors? And apart from this approach, Am I right with the assumption that arc costs are always stateless?

Comment: Yes, the assumptions is correct. And merging will help search down the way.